# How to set the Audio operation over player in my app?

Tags: android

I have created a fm app. I want to mute and unmute the player in my application. But it shows:

> Field requires API 23 curr min is 19..

My code is:

```
audioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_UNMUTE, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);

audioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is from using `AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE` and `AudioManager.ADJUST_UNMUTE` flags, which were incorporated in the API 23 (refer to docs here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#ADJUST_MUTE).

That basically means that your code is correct for APIs 23 and above, but for older Android versions you should use this method instead:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamMute(int%2C%20boolean)

You might want to make a conditional statement that will check for Android API used by the device and use `audioManager.adjustVolume(...)` for APIs 23 or higher or use `audioManager.setStreamMute(...)` for API 22 or lower.

Cheers!